# Why is the following interface contract not allowed?

Tags: java, interface

I'm thinking about offering a new feature to Java and I would like to ask why have it been restricted by design so far:

```
public abstract class BodyPart {
    abstract public void followBodyPart(BodyPart part);
}

public class Head extends BodyPart{
     public void followBodyPart(Body body ) { //Why is this kind of implementation not allowed? 
     ...
     }
}
public class Body extends BodyPart{
     public void followBodyPart(Head head ) { //and this
     ...
     }
     public void followBodyPart(Forearm leftForearm ) { //and also this
     ...
     }
     ...
}
//Arm, Forearm, etc...
```

Why is followBodyPart(Body body) in Head not implementing followBody in BodyPart? If it would, the advantages would be clear.

Firstly, the IDE would be able to offer within it's autocomplete feature Body objects as parameters to followBody instead of any other BodyParts objects that Head can not follow.

Secondly, the current version of Body consists of one function and many instanceof's, which could be eliminated.

Finally, generics can help here but not solve the problem, since this code should be ported to Java ME devices.

This question was already asked, in the not appropriate forum as I discovered [here](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=10424263&#10424263)

In regards to the answers, I invite you to think different. I understand that anything implementing BodyPart should accept **any** BodyPart, but: what I want is to be able to say that Head would be able to accept **A** BodyPart to follow.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question isn't really clear. Are you really asking a question or just making a point ? Are you looking for a solution to a problem ?

Comment: What do you mean by offering a new feature to Java? Have you posted a JSR?

Comment: I didn't post a JSR, but I'm thinking about it. Since I don't have too much experience in Java, I'm asking whether such feature is possible or not. I'm asking a question, however if the answers will not satisfy me I will be ready to make a point.

Comment: why not make BodyPart an interface?

Comment: He could do that. It still wouldn't help him.

Comment: "why not make BodyPart an interface?" It isn't relevant, even if it was an interface, the implementation as offered wouldn't implement it anyway. The answer is that it has another not abstract methods.

Comment: @Vitali Pom with an interface and generics it would be possible to set your classes up as you listed above (thats why I asked if you could use generics). Its too bad that this isnt an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question was also answered in the forum post you linked..

Namely; the interface defines the function should be able to accept *anything* that implements `BodyPart`.

By implementing the function in `Head` to *only* accept the subclass `Body`, but not any other subclass; you are violating that contract (since it no longer accepts anything implementing `BodyPart`).

Interfaces are usually used to provide to "external" code, allowing them to be sure that, whichever implementation of the interface is provided; they can for sure use the functions defined by the interface.

So if this external code gets an `BodyPart`, it knows it has a function `followBodyPart` that can accept *anything* extending `BodyPart` as argument. That external code will, however, never know that it got `Head` (or can, after casting it after an instanceof check) and thus cannot know that the interface function will *only* accept a `Body`.

---

By request; say that you provide the `BodyPart` interface as some kind of program API. In that case, I do not directly need to know what type of `BodyPart` it is. Now say that I have two of them; received through some functions in your API, for example with the signature: `public BodyPart getBody()`. The method states it *might* be a `Body` I get back; but it could as well be something else (fact is, I don't know!).

According to the `BodyPart` interface; I can call `followBodyPart` on the first `BodyPart`, and pass the second one in as argument. However, the actual `Body` implementation would not allow this; and there is no way for me to know that.

If you really want different classes to accept different entries; you should either drop the function from `BodyPart` and just implement it in the subclasses.

By passing those subclasses back from the API; everyone knows what they're talking with, and what it can do (e.g. `public Body getBody()` and `public Head getHead()`). Since I then have the actual implementation classes, which have the actual implementation with a certain `BodyPart` to 'follow', it isn't a problem.

An other option would be - but stated impossible in your question - to use generics; in such case you can define an Interface stating:

```
public interface Accepts<T extends BodyPart> {
    public void followBodyPart(T part);
}
```

And the API could pass back either the implemented `BodyPart`, or an `Accepts<Head>` instance, for example.
(Edit: as I wrote this here, I forgot to keep in mind you cannot implement the same interface more then once with different generic types; so the generic interface method would need the actual implementation to encapsulate objects that can actually handle the calls, making everything even more a mess)

Bonus edit: ofcourse you can also make `AcceptsHead`, `AcceptsArm` as interfaces and effectively working around the generics issue :).

I hope this edit clears up why it would be a weird (and bad) idea to have a generic interface (using `BodyPart` as argument), but only specify specific implementations in the (possibly hidden) implementation classes.

Comment: The answer is helpful and I added a response to your answer in my question. Could you give an example where any BodyPart is indeed needed (can be with your own classes), it can help the readers (me too).

Comment: In response to your bonus edit: imagine what would happen if you had 2k classes, you would double the amount of classes than. That is something that I wrote in Oracle but didn't mention here.

Comment: The interface way was mainly if you do not want to give back the actual object. In your case, I think you actually _want_ to give back the original object; and not use an interface method for the method `followBodyPart`, as it's too specific per implementation.

Comment: "Namely; the interface defines the function should be able to accept anything that implements BodyPart." and "According to the BodyPart interface; I can call followBodyPart on the first BodyPart, and pass the second one in as argument. However, the actual Body implementation would not allow this; and there is no way for me to know that." answer the question. I mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'm not quite intuitively understanding your class relationships - they are circular which is already an indication of a bad design.  I'm not saying you don't happen to NEED that particular structure - I would just suggest that some refactoring to remove the circularity might ultimately be a better design.

What it looks like you're trying to do is implement a visitor-pattern.  But if you have a reference to the base class, it could never trigger the invocation of the specialized methods - e.g. since the compiler can't pick the method you intended, then the runtime is just going to have to do the instance-of switching for you - it would only be syntactic sugar at best (look up scala, they actually do that).

```
def bodyPart(part:BodyPart) =>
  part match {
     Head(h) => /* do something with head h */
     Foot(f) => /* do something with foot f */
     Toe(t) => /* do something with toe t */
  }
```

The other way to solve this is to abstractly noop all possible visitor types:

```
public class BodyPart { // could have been abstract class
    public void followBodyPart(BodyPart part) { }
    public void followBodyPart(Head part) { }
    public void followBodyPart(Arm part) { }
    public void followBodyPart(Foot part) { }
    public void followBodyPart(Toe part) { }
}
public class Head { ... /* only implements Head, BodyPart, others error */ }
public class Arm { ... /* only implements Arm, Abdomen, etc */ }
```

Now the visitor invoker will staticly choose the correct method at compile time.  But it needs more plumbing in each implementation because it needs to decide how to properly handle all the other input types.  But that's a good thing - it removes ambiguity.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think a good thing. What will you do with the other inputs? Throw an exception? See my edited question, the difference between **any** and **a**.